# Read and rewrite body from request and response with spring gateway filter

Tags: filter, reactive, spring-cloud-gateway

My problem is to read and rewrite the HTTP request/response body in the same gateway filter (Spring cloud).

After several searchs, I prefer to use decorator but it does not work to get body response.

Code :

```java
public class AuthorizationGatewayFilterFactory
        extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthorizationGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {
    
    //...

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            LOG.info("Pre-processing");

            ServerHttpRequestDecorator loggingServerHttpRequestDecorator = new ServerHttpRequestDecorator(exchange.getRequest()) {
                String requestBody = "";

                @Override
                public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
                    return super.getBody().doOnNext(dataBuffer -> {
                        try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                            Channels.newChannel(byteArrayOutputStream)
                                    .write(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().asReadOnlyBuffer());
                            requestBody = IOUtils.toString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
                            LOG.info("requestBody: " + requestBody);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            //ignore
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            
            ServerHttpResponse originalResponse = exchange.getResponse();
            DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = originalResponse.bufferFactory();

            ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(originalResponse) {
                @Override
                public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                    if (body instanceof Flux) {
                        Flux<? extends DataBuffer> fluxBody = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;
                        return super.writeWith(fluxBody.map(dataBuffer -> {
                            byte[] content = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                            dataBuffer.read(content);
                            LOG.info("Response : {}", new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                            return bufferFactory.wrap(content);
                        }));
                    }
                    return super.writeWith(body);
                }
            }; 
            
            
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(loggingServerHttpRequestDecorator).response(decoratedResponse).build()).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                LOG.info("Post-processing");
            }));
            
            
        };
    }
}
```

Output/Result in log :

```
...AuthorizationGatewayFilterFactory : requestBody: HelloRequest
...AuthorizationGatewayFilterFactory : Post-processing
```

I send this request to gateway :
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/users/test6' 
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' 
--data 'HelloRequest'

Response from proxied service:
HTTP 200 Hello2

Why response body is not logged (for testing but I need to rewrite after that)?

---

UPDATE

Here is an alternative to decorators with this minimal example:

1. Client sends [POST http://localhost:8080/some/path bonjour] to Gateway
2. Gateway sends [POST http://localhost:8081/some/path hello] to Service proxy
3. Service proxy returns [hello] to Gateway
4. Gateway returns [Bonjour] to Client

Declare route:

```java
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
            return builder.routes()
                .route("routeId", r -> r.method(HttpMethod.POST).and().path("/some/path").filters(filtersToApply()).uri("http://localhost:8081"))
                .build();
    }
```

Filters to apply:

```java
    private Function<GatewayFilterSpec, UriSpec> filtersToApply() {
        return f -> {
            
            f.modifyRequestBody(String.class, String.class, (exchange, originalRequest) -> {
                log.info("Pre-processing");
                log.debug("originalRequest=" + originalRequest);
                final String newRequest = "Hello";
                log.debug("newRequest=" + newRequest);
                return Mono.just(newRequest);
            });
            
            f.modifyResponseBody(String.class, String.class, (exchange, originalResponse) -> {
                log.info("Post-processing");
                log.debug("Post-processing: originalResponse=" + originalResponse);
                final String newResponse = "Bonjour";
                log.debug("newResponse=" + newResponse);
                return Mono.just(newResponse);
            });
                        
            return f;
        };
    }
```

Request to gateway:

```
    curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/some/path' \
    --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
    --data 'bonjour'
```

Result in log gateway:

```
     INFO : Pre-processing
    DEBUG : originalRequest=bonjour
    DEBUG : newRequest=Hello
     INFO : Post-processing
    DEBUG : Post-processing: originalResponse=hello
    DEBUG : newResponse=Bonjour
```

Comment: I've checked the ModifyResponseGatewayFilter that is implementing the "f.modifyRequestBody" your are using. and it's implementing Ordered interface by 

```
@Override
  public int getOrder() {
   return NettyWriteResponseFilter.WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER - 1;
  }
```

after added this to my self implement GatewayFilter, the response decorator is working.